# Add dictionary to another dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary

Here is my code for adding dictionary in another dictionary

```
dict_temp = {}
logs = {}
for d in e:
        count +=1
        dict_temp['email']= d["sent_to"]
        dict_temp['log_id']= d["unique_arguments"]
        print dict_temp
        logs[count] = dict_temp
        dict_temp.clear()
    print logs
```

the dictionary dict_temp is perfectly built, but when i add this dictionary into the logs dictonar have a look at the dictionary when i print it, it is empty..
and here is the output;

```
    {'log_id': u'log_1_taqi.official@gmail.com', 'email': u'taqi.official@gmail.com'}                                                                                                            
{'log_id': u'log_1_taqi.hass@cogilent.com', 'email': u'taqi.hass@cogilent.com'}                                                                                                              
{'log_id': u'log_1_taqi.official@gmailllllll.com', 'email': u'taqi.official@gmailllllll.com'}                                                                                                
{'log_id': u'log_2_taqi.official@gmail.com', 'email': u'taqi.official@gmail.com'}                                                                                                            
{'log_id': u'log_2_taqi.hass@cogilent.com', 'email': u'taqi.hass@cogilent.com'}                                                                                                              
{'log_id': u'log_2_taqi.official@gmailllllll.com', 'email': u'taqi.official@gmailllllll.com'}                                                                                                
{'log_id': u'log_4_taqi.official@gmail.com', 'email': u'taqi.official@gmail.com'}                                                                                                            
{'log_id': u'log_4_taqi.hass@cogilent.com', 'email': u'taqi.hass@cogilent.com'}                                                                                                              
{'log_id': u'log_4_taqi.official@gmailllllll.com', 'email': u'taqi.official@gmailllllll.com'}                                                                                                
{'log_id': u'log_5_taqi.official@gmail.com', 'email': u'taqi.official@gmail.com'}                                                                                                            
{'log_id': u'log_5_taqi.hass@cogilent.com', 'email': u'taqi.hass@cogilent.com'}                                                                                                              
{'log_id': u'log_5_taqi.official@gmailllllll.com', 'email': u'taqi.official@gmailllllll.com'}                                                                                                
{'log_id': u'log_6_taqi.official@gmail.com', 'email': u'taqi.official@gmail.com'}                                                                                                            
{'log_id': u'log_6_taqi.hass@cogilent.com', 'email': u'taqi.hass@cogilent.com'}                                                                                                              
{'log_id': u'log_6_taqi.official@gmailllllll.com', 'email': u'taqi.official@gmailllllll.com'}                                                                                                
{'log_id': u'log_7_taqi.official@gmail.com', 'email': u'taqi.official@gmail.com'}                                                                                                            
{'log_id': u'log_7_taqi.hass@cogilent.com', 'email': u'taqi.hass@cogilent.com'}                                                                                                              
{'log_id': u'log_7_taqi.official@gmailllllll.com', 'email': u'taqi.official@gmailllllll.com'}                                                                                                
{'log_id': u'log_8_taqi.official@gmail.com', 'email': u'taqi.official@gmail.com'}                                                                                                            
{'log_id': u'log_8_taqi.hass@cogilent.com', 'email': u'taqi.hass@cogilent.com'}                                                                                                              
{'log_id': u'log_8_taqi.official@gmailllllll.com', 'email': u'taqi.official@gmailllllll.com'}                                                                                                
{1: {}, 2: {}, 3: {}, 4: {}, 5: {}, 6: {}, 7: {}, 8: {}, 9: {}, 10: {}, 11: {}, 12: {}, 13: {}, 14: {}, 15: {}, 16: {}, 17: {}, 18: {}, 19: {}, 20: {}, 21: {}}
```

Comment: Hint: Check `[id(x) for x in logs.values()]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are adding the *same dictionary object* over and over again. You are not adding a copy. As such, you'll end up with all references to that dictionary showing the same contents:

```
>>> inner = {}
>>> outer = {}
>>> inner['foo'] = 'bar'
>>> outer['inner_key'] = inner
>>> outer
{'inner_key': {'foo': 'bar'}}
>>> inner['foo'] = 'baz'
>>> outer
{'inner_key': {'foo': 'baz'}}
>>> inner.clear()
>>> outer
{'inner_key': {}}
>>> outer['another_key'] = inner
>>> outer
{'another_key': {}, 'inner_key': {}}
>>> inner['foo'] = 'spam'
>>> outer
{'another_key': {'foo': 'spam'}, 'inner_key': {'foo': 'spam'}}
```

Note how any changes to `inner` are reflected when printing the `outer` dictionary, because both share the same object. Adding more keys to point to this one dictionary only created more references, not copies:

```
>>> id(inner), id(outer['inner_key']), id(outer['another_key'])
(4413825104, 4413825104, 4413825104)
>>> inner is outer['inner_key']
True
>>> inner is outer['another_key']
True
```

Use a *new dictionary*:

```
logs = {}
for d in e:
    count +=1
    new_dict = {'email': d["sent_to"], 'log_id': d["unique_arguments"]}
    logs[count] = new_dict
```

Another option would be to create a (shallow) copy of the dictionary using [`dict.copy()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.copy), but since you are replacing both keys entirely *anyway* there is really no point in doing so here.